# Finding ALL matches after a certain character(s)

Tags: regex

I'd like to think I'm ok at writing RegEx's, but there's one thing I can't seem to crack:

I want to start looking for **multiple**, **identical** matches after a certain set of characters and capture all of them. Here's an example string:

```
Dialogue: 0,0:05:47.99,0:05:50.74,JoJo-main,Koichi,0000,0000,0000,,What are you doing, Giorno Giovanna?!
```

For this example, I want to start looking for matches after `,,`. I want to find all instances of `Gio` i.e.

```
Dialogue: 0,0:05:47.99,0:05:50.74,JoJo-main,Koichi,0000,0000,0000,,What are you doing, {Gio}rno {Gio}vanna?!
```

I've tried first using non-capturing groups like `/(?:,,.*?)(Gio)/g` then lookbehinds like `/(?<=,,.*?)(Gio)/g`, `/(?<=,,)(?:.*?)(Gio)/g` and `/(?<=,,)((?:.*?)(Gio))+/g` to avoid consuming the `,,`

None of these give me the behaviour I want, as I want individual matches as if I just used `Gio`, but without the chance of accidentally capturing stuff before the `,,`

I could, of course, run one RegEx to find the `,,` then feed that position to another RegEx to look for `Gio`s after that point.
However I have thousands of lines like these to parse and thousands of words to look for on each line (I separate them with `|`), so I'd ideally like to do it with one RegEx and without a loop.

Comment: `/(?<=,,.*?)Gio/g`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5QuxM/1). `(?:\G(?!^)|,,).*?\KGio` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5QuxM/2))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah! Brilliant. I tried something similar to (1) before, but it gave me errors of "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length", and a quick google seemed to imply that method was impossible.
Please do post both as a joint-answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider the following option for the .NET or modern ECMAScript 2018+ compliant JS environments:

```
/(?<=,,.*?)Gio/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5QuxM/1).

The `(?<=,,.*?)Gio` pattern matches `Gio` when it is preceded with `,,` and any 0+ chars other  than line break chars, as few as possible.

The following variant will work with PCRE/Onigmo regex engines:

```
/(?:\G(?!^)|,,).*?\KGio/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5QuxM/2). Here, `(?:\G(?!^)|,,)` matches either the end of the previous successful match or `,,` and then `.*?` matches and consumes any 0+ chars other  than line break chars, as few as possible, then `\K` will reset the match buffer and `Gio` will land right there.